# How to strictly compare two long numeric string in awk

Tags: awk, string-comparison

I wrote some awk script to process some data, and found the result unexpected.

I found the root cause is that the following string comparison is not correct

```
echo "59558711052462309110012 59558711052462313120012"|awk '{print $1;print $2;print ($1==$2)?"eq":"ne"}'
```

The result is

```
59558711052462309110012
59558711052462313120012
eq
```

I guess the reason is that awk treats the two numeric strings as numbers, and cuts off them to compare.
My question is that how can I strictly compare the two strings in awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Force a string comparison by telling awk that at least one of the operands IS a string by concatenating that operand with the null string:

```
echo "59558711052462309110012 59558711052462313120012"|
awk '{print $1;print $2;print ($1""==$2)?"eq":"ne"}'
59558711052462309110012
59558711052462313120012
ne
```

Comment: so awk will do numberic comparision if I didn't concatenate the operand with null string  and cuts off the operand if the length exceeds?

Comment: With no modification awk will try to figure out if you want a numeric or string comparison. As long as both sides "look like" (by awks reasoning) numbers the comparison will be numeric, otherwise it'll be string. idk what `cuts off the operand if the length exceeds` means.

Answer (score 0):

`@EdMorton`'s solution already fails when a positive sign exists in front of it, all else being equal :

```
 echo '59558711052462309110012' | mawk '1; 1' | 
 mawk '($++NF = (!_?_="+":_=__) $!__)^__'     | ...
```

> ```
>  ... | awk ' { print $0, "\f\r\t" ( ($1""==$2) ? "eq" : "ne" ) }'
> ```

```
 1  59558711052462309110012 +59558711052462309110012
    ne
 2  59558711052462309110012  59558711052462309110012 
    eq
```